# Accessing Android UI toolkit from worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

According to Android doc,
"...Additionally, the Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:

Do not block the UI thread
Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread"

That seems very plausible, but is it correct that the compiler does NOT complain at all if a programmer violates the second rule?

Answer (score 1):

You will not get a compile-time error.  You may (or may not) get a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to update UI like

1. [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
2. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
3. runOnUiThread method of View
4. [BroascastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: KPBird, I was just experimenting with Handlers's post method (from a worker thread), when I realized that I was able to update the TextView's text without using myHadler.post(Runnable r) method. However, when I increased the number of posts to 1000 times (using a for loop), I get the following exception:05-11 00:55:27.473: E/AndroidRuntime(2022): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.